# Xcode UI testing collection view cells became non-hittable on iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode-ui-testing

We were using this code to simulate a tap on the first cell of a `UICollectionView` on Xcode UI Testing:

```
XCUIElementQuery *query = [application descendantsMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeAny];
XCUIElement *collectionView = [query objectForKeyedSubscript:collectionViewAccessibilityIdentifier];
XCUIElement *targetCell = [lensesCollectionView.cells elementBoundByIndex:cellIndex];
if (targetCell.hittable) {
    [targetCell tap];
}
```

this works fine on iOS 10, but stopped working on iOS 11. The `targetCell` is never `hittable` no matter what. Adding a `sleep(10)` before `XCUIElement *targetCell = [lensesCollectionView.cells elementBoundByIndex:lensIndex]` doesn't help.

I've seen hacky solutions mentioned elsewhere such as

```
func forceTapElement() {   
    if self.isHittable {   
        self.tap()   
    } else {   
        var coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0))   
        coordinate.tap()   
    }  
}
```

but that doesn't look very clean. What's the cleanest way of achieving this?

---

*Update*: If I try to tap it without checking for `hittable` I get this error:

> error: Error -25204 performing AXAction 2003 on element  pid: 43616, elementOrHash.elementID: 4882574576.240

Comment: I had this problem with cells which were not on-screen - they used to be auto-scrolled onto the screen before tapping when run on iOS 10. Is your cell definitely on-screen when you try to tap it?

Comment: It is definitely on the screen. I can see it on the phone, and the `targetCell.frame` is inside the screen. Yet, it remains untappable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that `isAccessibilityElement` was `NO` on our custom *collection view cells* on *iOS 11* (strangely, it was `YES` on *iOS 10*). Explicitly setting it to `YES` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Ricardo should be the accepted one.
For clarity, we had the same issue and solved it in the Class file of the UICollectionViewCell.
In `initWithCoder:` we just added property `isAccessibilityElement`:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

    if (self != nil) {
        self.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    }

    return self;
}
```

We could now run the same test script form Xcode 8 in Xcode 9.1 and the cell was tapped properly.

Thanks for this great solution.